# Are GIT refs always case insensitive?

Tags: git

I was testing on my local machine (OS-X 10.10) which uses a case insensitive file system (HFS+ [CI]) - when I reset to the head:

```
$ git reset head --hard
$ git reset HEAD --hard
```

and

```
$ git checkout 4f2c
$ git checkout 4F2C
```

Have the exact same results. To my understanding GIT stores refs inside `./git/refs` but does the case sensitivity of the underlying file system affect the results?

Would I get the same results on a case sensitive file system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are case insensitive. No, a case sensitive file system will not matter. Because [`git` refs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) are part of a [SHA-1 hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), and those are hexadecimal digits (base-16, they just look like letters). At least for the commit-id. As pointed out by [@EdwardThomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson) in the comments, a *ref-name* may (or may not) be case-sensitive (that depends on the underlying filesystem and whether or not the storage mechanism is loose or packed).

Comment: The commit id that is the *target* of a ref is a hex string, but the ref name itself is a string (eg "master").  It may be treated case sensitively (or not) depending on the storage mechanism (loose or packed) and the underlying filesystem semantics.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Thank you for the *extremely* constructive comment, edited my answer.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Case-insensitivity of ref names is arguably a bug in git and is dangerous to rely on. For example, if you use the (not so new) "git worktree" feature on a case-insensitive filesystem, you'll find that "head" refers to the main worktree HEAD, not the current worktree HEAD. This is extremely confusing at best, and sometimes disastrous.

Comment: I think the first sentence of this answer is very misleading, as even statements later in the answer contradict it. I don't know all the nuances otherwise I'd edit it myself, but clearly you can't say the first statement, especially since "they" must refer to all of the cases given in the question, not just commit hashes.

Answer (score 5):

No, you would not get the same results on a case sensitive filesystem.  If you ran:

```
git reset branch --head
```

on a case sensitive filesystem then that is not the same as running:

```
git reset BRANCH --hard
```

Since references are often stored on the filesystem (in the `.git/refs/heads` folder), the case sensitivity of the filesystem comes into play.  On a case sensitive filesystem, `.git/refs/heads/branch` and `.git/refs/heads/BRANCH` are two different files.

Note that even on a case insensitive filesystem, your references may end up "packed", in a file specifying on reference per line.  In this case, your references are always case sensitive, regardless of your filesystem.

Comment: Is there a simple logic to when references are "packed"?