# Getting an error when trying to run `git rebase --continue`, cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/Head-feature'

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm running the command `git rebase --continue` and getting an error:

`error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/heads/HEAD-feature': cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/HEAD-feature': is at db50dd34de1e90c0616bf9318be489ee8d9a012a but expected 83f09532b2352418c0f562f48929dc504e6a0452 error: could not update refs/heads/HEAD-feature`

I looked at a couple similar questions but none of the answers worked.

I tried the following:

```
1. git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/HEAD-feature
2. git --no-optional-locks fetch --prune origin
3. git gc --prune=now
4. git remote prune origin
```

The only way I've found to overcome this is to do `git rebase --abort` but then I lose all the changes I made during an interactive rebase. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this always happen for you when you `git rebase --continue`? Does #1 go well? It comes with some validation. You could try to delete `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD-feature` manually from disk and then `git fetch` again?

Comment: It seems to run fine but then still I still run into an issue with `git rebase --continue`

Comment: Did you try deleting the refs manually (not using git update-ref) and fetching again?

Comment: hm, in my case my ref is only locally available I haven't put it to remote yet. I tried doing `git reset HEAD^` to remove the changes and stash them then `git rebase --continue` but it seems to have the same issue

Comment: Aha, okay. Got confused because your commands involved `origin`. Is the issue only with *this* rebase or is it a general issue? "cannot lock ref" usually means some sort of general corruption of the `.git/refs` folder.

Comment: It seems a general issue when I make a change on this stack of commits I have. It doesn't happen all the time but it does happen multiple times

Comment: The name `HEAD-feature` is a bit weird (why have a branch whose name is mixed case? use all-lower-case to avoid case issues on Windows and macOS) but I suspect the actual problem might be putting a Git repository in a network-drive folder (Google Drive, iCloud, Dropbox, etc). Don't do that.

Answer (score 14):

### You or some rogue process was messing with your repo state in a way that conflicts with `git rebase`

The error message indicates that you or someone else or something did something to your repo state, something that you can't do while a rebase is in progress. It was expecting a ref to point to a specific commit, but it got changed out from under it.

### How to recover

Here's how to recover from the situation without losing all your rebase work so-far (assuming you haven't yet aborted):

1. ##### Save your rebase progress so-far

   ```bash
   git branch PARTIAL-REBASE HEAD
   ```

   This will create a branch ref named `PARTIAL-REBASE` pointing to the last rebased commit -- i.e. your rebase work so far.

   You must do this *before* `git rebase --abort`, otherwise you'll have to search the reflogs to recover your partial rebase, which is more complicated.
2. ##### Abort the rebase

   ```bash
   git rebase --abort
   ```
3. ##### Resume the rebase where it left off

   There are many ways to do this, but this is the easiest.

   First see which commits are included in your saved partial rebase:

   ```bash
   git log PARTIAL-REBASE
   ```

   Make sure you are on the correct branch, then rerun your
   original rebase command, but add the following
   options to the command:

   ```bash
   --onto PARTIAL-REBASE --interactive
   ```

   A list of commits to rebase will appear in an editor.
   Carefully delete only those lines for the commits that are
   already included in the git log for `PARTIAL-REBASE` above.
   DO NOT make any other changes unless you know what you are
   doing.

   Save and close the rebase list. The commits in the rebase list
   will now be rebased *onto* `PARTIAL-REBASE`, effectively
   resuming your rebase at the point you aborted it.
4. #### Verify and cleanup

   Verify that your rebased branch is good.

   When you're sure that your rebase was successful and all is good, delete the `PARTIAL-REBASE` ref:

   ```
   git branch -D PARTIAL-REBASE
   ```

See also [How to fix "corrupted" interactive rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685001/how-to-fix-corrupted-interactive-rebase) and [Git rebase failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695044/git-rebase-failing), though I'm surprised that no one gave a "How to recover" solution such as mine.

Comment: From `git branch PARTIAL-REBASE head` I get `fatal: Not a valid object name: 'head'.`(?) Also *look at the history and …* Do I get that from `git log`?

Comment: @OleV.V. I changed step 3 to make it much easier for beginning git users. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reverting on my questions to your answer from last year. *What happens if you run `git log head`?* The answer I get now may not tell anything since I have now aborted the rebase without saving my work and rebased from scratch. In any case I will try when I get to my work computer tomorrow.

Comment: *I changed step 3 to make it much easier for beginning git users.* It indeed looks manageable now. :-)

Comment: It’s not a problem for me any more, so just in an attempt to reply: even after having aborted and redone the rebase and also pulling, from `git branch PARTIAL-REBASE head` I still get `fatal: Not a valid object name: 'head'.`. However in capitals it worked: `git branch PARTIAL-REBASE HEAD`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Does `git log head` work, or do you also have to type `git log HEAD`? I think I have found the cause: I'll bet you have a case-sensitive file system. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102642/are-git-refs-always-case-insensitive. I've update the answer so that it works for such filesystems.

Comment: Yes, I am on Linux, its file names are case sensitive. Thanks for updating.

Comment: `git log head` in lower case gives me `fatal: ambiguous argument 'head': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`. With upper case `HEAD` it works, gives me the history.